# boothstrap4: overlap columns on smaller screens

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've 2 columns bootstrap4 layout where first-half is intended to be an image and the other half will have a form. However, I want the second column to overlap first on small screens instead of wrapping down below the first column.

How can this be achieved?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 h-100 bgcolumn">
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-6 h-100 text-center">
      <h1>
      HELLO
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/90676/

Comment: You will have to write a media query to achieve this. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/95b4necg/

Comment: I was doubtful if bootstrap has something inbuilt or I'd need to use media queries. Seems later is the case. Thanks for very helpful jsfiddle @NiK648